# How to hide class access?

Tags: c#

I want to have one project able to access certain classes and not others in a separate project, but that separate project's classes should have access to all of its own classes.  For example:

```
Project 1 :namespace 1
       Class A (Can access C, but not D)
       Class B (Can access C, but not D)
Project 2 :namespace 2
       Class C (Can be access D)
       Class D
```

I want my Class A to be able to access Class C and not Class D, but my class C should be able to access Class D.

Comment: Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx

Comment: Get a read on access modifers

Answer (score 1):

Specify the class D as **internal** instead of **public**

Answer (score 1):

Use Internal, then it'll be available only within the assembly.

Read more at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Set Class D as Internal rather than as public.
This will Help you.